# Django: correct way to display dynamic images from arbitrary path

Tags: python, django

In my django app there is a model with CharField "avatar", storing the filename of object's picture (different for each object). Pictures themselves are stored in certain directory on the same host, but not inside the app directory. Say, django app is in /home/djadmin/myapp and images are in /tmp/avatars.
Objects and images are frequently added/updated/deleted via other process (basically, images are uploaded to my host by ftp).

I need to show these images in django template. Say, if field "avatar" stores "123.jpg" than I have to show image from path /tmp/avatars/123.jpg.

**How can I display these images using "img" tag in django template?**

I guess addind /tmp/avatars to STATICFILES_DIRS is not an option, because my images are not 'static'.

Comment: It's common to serve images from nginx or apache. You are right that you should not use django's staticfiles for this. The simplest solution is just to give nginx/apache read access to your avatar folder, and serve `/avatars/` from there with a location directive in your nginx/apache site config. In the django template, you can just use `<img src=/avatars/{{user.avatar}} />` or something like that.